# light-weight chart add custom candle serie label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightweight-charts

I want to create candle serie price label like bottom image.

I want to add how much time to next candle in price label.

[image]

i showed my purpose of this question with yellow line

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not implemented yet in `lightweight-charts` library, you can track https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/363 to be notified when it will be ready and also put your feedback or  to the issue.